# Trigger java code on click events in Microsoft Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, click

Is there any way that, upon clicking on a particular cell in excel, I can make a call to java code with details in that cell? Details could be, cell data + row number + column number, etc.

I'm just exploring. I see something called Apache POI -> https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/

Would this satisfy my use-case?

Thanks,
Anusha

Comment: Even't doesn't control with Java. You might consider reading about excel formulas.

Comment: No, it would not.  POI is about writing and parsing Excel sheets.  Nothing to do with when you have the sheet open in Excel.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve, out of interest?

Comment: Just exploring options to create, say, an email. The cell details could have the email address, and upon a click, you want to email the person with some pre-decided email format. Not the best example to give, but I'm just exploring ways to make such things happen. We're having a hackathon in my office, so, trying to think of some ideas for that. Thanks for the answers though. I suppose I'd have to find some workarounds.

Comment: Ron de Bruin has every conceivable scenario for sending emails from Excel with VBA. No need to re-invent and jump through Java hoops. Just use what comes with Excel natively, and that is VBA. https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section1.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Excel events can only be cought using VBA. (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel )

Theoretically you could use VBA to do anything, so even start a java program and feeding it the data you need as arguments. But I don't see many use cases where 
it isn't simpler to do the whole thing in VBA.

But if you wanted to make one cell look like a button, kicking off your mailer program, you could.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   'maybe first save your exel file, perhaps even to a temp location
   'so your java program can access the data.
   'you can also directly provide the data you need to your java program
   'if it's little enough to be passed as a command line parameter.

   Dim strProgramName As String
   Dim strArgument As String

   strProgramName = "C:\.....\java.exe"
   strArgument = "C:\....\yourjavaprogram " + "yourexcelfilelocation"

   Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```